# In my JSF 2.2 web app while user is logged in via BASIC Auth sites with iframe content are not shown (they are empty)

Tags: jsf, iframe, basic-authentication

My **JSF 2.2 web-app** has some sites that uses **BASIC auth.** as long the user is NOT logged in all sites with iframes (external content on a other server) working fine ("local" sites too).
On user login the iframe sites does NOT work anymore (shown empty) - all the "local" sites with and without BASIC auth are still fine.

**Remarks:** 

- The sites with iframes are **not part** of the BASIC Auth scope. Means they are accessable without login.

- The JSF web-app runing on wildfly 10.1.0 - the content of the iframes are hosted on a Tomcat.

**QUESTIONs:** 

- Why does the iframe sites on user login dont work anymore?

- How can I prevent this?

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">


    <ui:define name="implementation">

        <h:form>

            <iframe src="http://myTomcatServer:8080/myContent/erkennungsquote.htm" 
                    width="100%" 
                    height="1000" 
                    frameborder="0"/>

        </h:form>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: How is this JSF related (or Java-se?) Try creating a [mcve] (remove the template) if it still does not work it is 100% not JSF related. Most likely some cross origin problem. Off-topic: With JSF-2.2 you can use newer namespace declarations

Comment: Yup. JSF is in the context of this problem merely a HTML page generator. Create a plain HTML page. Does it still fail, then it's absolutely not JSF related. You'd have had exactly the same problem with any other server side framework which produces HTML pages. This way you can better drill down your search keywords and hence improve the search results, and if in vain, create a better focused question targeting the more correct audience.